# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng cannot be cast to com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng

Tags: android, casting, maps, mapbox, latitude-longitude

I am trying to create an app for loading some points on map using mapbox. On login, the intent is passed into second activity from the main activity. Here is the code of passing intent from main activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST", (Serializable) latlngs);
intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
startActivity(intent);
```

latlngs contains the value as [lat/lng: (48.85819, 2.29458), lat/lng: (48.88519, 2.24958)]

This is my second activity.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs_second = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Mapbox.getInstance(this, "access token");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    latlngs_second = (ArrayList<LatLng>) 
    args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
    System.out.println("value: " + latlngs_second.get(0));

    // Mapbox Access token
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, new 
            Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                }
            });
            mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latlngs_second.get(0))
                    .title("markers")); // first tried to plot one point
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to run the app, it crashes and getting following error.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.logindemo, PID: 16753
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng cannot be cast to com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng
        at com.example.logindemo.SecondActivity$1.onMapReady(SecondActivity.java:57)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onMapReady(MapView.java:1240)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.initialised(MapView.java:1226)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialiseMap(MapView.java:211)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.access$800(MapView.java:63)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$6.run(MapView.java:325)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Can anybody help to resolve it?

Comment: Check your import for _LatLng_

Comment: @Piyush I have imported this one
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

Comment: That's the issue

Comment: when we are using mapbox, we have to import  "import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;" right? otherwise 

mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latlngs_second.get(0))
                    .title("markers")); 
will show error

Answer (score 0):

I came here because i had the same error, what fixed it for me was not changing the import from previous answers, but chaging the import from MarkerOptions()